# How can I remove the page titles in the Twenty Thirteen Theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

All pages in the `Twenty Thirteen` theme display the page's title at the top of the page's content. How can I remove it from all pages?

Answer (score 1):

you can add css in your theme style sheet

```
.page .entry-title {
       display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can that be done from the Wordpress interface without needing file-level access to the web server?

Comment: Yes go to personalize -> add custom css

Answer (score 0):

Open `wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/page.php` in a text editor and replace the following line:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

with:

```
<!--<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>-->
```